# Sitefinity related items and DynamicContent with Babaganoush model

Tags: c#, sitefinity, babaganoush-sitefinity

I am currently trying to convert my handcrafted models for a sitefinity DynamicContent to Babaganoush models.  Everything is working well apart from the relatedItems.

I can see in the demo there is a SetRelation method, but the associated get in the demo is GetImage (as the related item is of type image).  Is there a GetDynamicContent method?

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction to get a related DynamicContent type into my model?

I have created Babaganoush models for the related items.

Comment: What type(s) are the related items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FooFoo sample has an example of related items working for your Babaganoush models. In your model's constructor, it will look like this:

```
// Single related item
var sfEvent = sfContent.GetOriginal().GetRelatedItems<Event>("Event").FirstOrDefault();
if (sfEvent != null)
{
    Event = new EventModel(sfEvent);
}

// List of related items
Sessions = sfContent.GetOriginal().GetRelatedItems<DynamicContent>("Sessions")
    .Select(x => new SessionModel(x))
    .ToList();
```

It's annoying that you have to get the original item from Sitefinity before you can get related items *sometimes*, so we hope to bury this inconsistency behind an extension one day (more complicated than it sounds for the scenario).

The FooFoo sample project can be found here by the way: https://github.com/FalafelSoftwareInc/Babaganoush.Sitefinity.Samples.FooFoo

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/related-data-api-examples

Should be some this like:

item.GetRelatedItems< Image >();

That would get you a list. You could always use FirstOrDefault()

Good luck